# I sent ERC20 to Ethereum wallet that doesn't accept tokens. Is there any way I can recover it?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, metamask

So after creating the smart chain bnb network on metamas I swapped my BNB to ETH and sent it to a casino account. apparently those were ETH tokens and they don't accept them. Are there any ways I can recover it?

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x91cc1c08b65d721d9586e14cb4c6e7e0d0c3c18a9388c4317f05e62544d76c80

Answer (score 0):

Not unless that contract supports Erc20 withdrawal in it's implementation, which is a very slim chance of it being the case. You could read more about that [here](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/10tokens.asciidoc#sending-erc20-tokens-to-contract-addresses).